# On Change Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to populate the alert boxes and then would like to enable Submit Button if all conditions passed, the basic jquery code is here:

```
$("#expCurrencyState").on("change", function() {
    var inputValue = document.getElementById('categoryItem').value;
    var expenseStateValue = document.getElementById('expCurrencyState').value;
    var expAmountValue = document.getElementById('expAmount').value;
    var expDateValue = document.getElementById('expDate').value;

    alert(inputValue);
    alert(expAmountValue);
    alert(expDateValue);
    alert(expenseStateValue);

    if (inputValue.length && expAmountValue.length && expDateValue.length !== 0) {
        alert('passed');
        $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#btnSubmit').addClass('btnActive');
    }
});
```

Comment: We can't really do much without your HTML code, please edit your question

Comment: Do you have an issue with this code? It looks fine, and you've not told us there's any problems with it

Answer (score 0):

The only problem i see is that you only check when the `#expCurrencyState` changes.

You should run that code on each of the required elements `change` event, and you should also disable the button and remove the class if not all conditions pass.

```
$("#expCurrencyState,#categoryItem,#expAmount,#expDate").on("change", function() {
    var inputValue = document.getElementById('categoryItem').value;
    var expenseStateValue = document.getElementById('expCurrencyState').value;
    var expAmountValue = document.getElementById('expAmount').value;
    var expDateValue = document.getElementById('expDate').value;

    var validData = inputValue.length && expAmountValue.length && expDateValue.length && expenseStateValue.length;

    if ( validData  ) {
        alert('passed');
    }

    $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', !validData); 
    $('#btnSubmit').toggleClass('btnActive', validData);
});
```